# Функция как параметр, вывод по словам

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы функция выводила по словам фразу либо в алерт либо в консоль. Но получается только построчно. Почему?

```
function toConsole (consoleParam) {
    consoleParam.toString();
    console.log(consoleParam);
}

function toAlert (alertParam) {
    alert(alertParam);
}

function splitToWords (msg, callback) {
    let result = msg.split(' '); 
    callback(result);
    
}

splitToWords('Я не знаю как это сделать', toConsole);
splitToWords('Я не знаю как это сделать', toAlert);
splitToWords('Я не знаю как это сделать');
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас получается не построчно, а массив. Добавьте цикл или переносы.

```js
function toConsole (consoleParam) {
    console.log(consoleParam.join('\n'));
}

function toAlert (alertParam) {
    alert(alertParam.join('\n'));
}

function splitToWords (msg, callback) {
    let result = msg.split(' '); 
    callback(result);
    
}

splitToWords('Я не знаю как это сделать', toConsole);
```

Comment: А если каждое слово в отдельный алерт?

Comment: Тогда цикл по массиву. Можно `alertParam.forEach(word => alert(word))`

Comment: `result.forEach(item => callback(item));`

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Решение от Igor скорее всего более корректно в контексте поставленной задачи)

Comment: В любом случае, получилось. Непонятно было, куда цикл вставлять